# Left Join on Many-to-One Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a reference to call that may or may not be there.  When I add the nullable option it still doing Inner Join when I want an Left Join (show the left even if the right is null).  Is this possible in the NH map?

```
References(x => x.DefaultCategory, "CATEGORY_ID")
    .Nullable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join type isn't specified in the mapping, but in the query.

IN HQL, use left join syntax as with SQL.

With Criteria, use:

```
.CreateAlias("categories", "c", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```

Comment: So you can never have a many-to-one reference that is null?  That seems a bit odd.

Comment: What you are suggesting works, but I question is there a better way?  I would be putting what feels like mapping logic into my repository thus causing a maintainability issue, no?

Comment: It isn't mapping, it's query logic.  It's just as valid to perform an inner join here, but it depends on the requirements of your app